# How can I style a definition list like a table?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a `<dl>` that has the appearance of a 2 column table, but am having some trouble getting the styling correct and would love some feedback!

This is the mockup of what I am trying to accomplish:
[image: mockup]

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/Nomad33/pen/PQwpyr) of my attempts so far.

my markup is a standard `<dl>` where there can be multiple `<dt>`s for a `<dd>` or multiple `<dd>`'s for a `<dt>`.

```
<dl class="b-references">
  <dt class="b-references__term">Director</dt>
    <dd class="b-references__item">Edgar Wright</dd>
  <dt class="b-references__term">Cast</dt>
    <dd class="b-references__item">Ansel Elgort</dd>
    <dd class="b-references__item">Lily James</dd>
    <dd class="b-references__item">Jon Hamm</dd>
    <dd class="b-references__item">Jamie Foxx</dd>
    <dd class="b-references__item">Kevin Spacy</dd>
    <dd class="b-references__item">Elza Gonzalez</dd>
    <dd class="b-references__item">Jon Bernthal</dd>
</dl>
```

and here is as close as I could get with the styles (SCSS):

```
.b-references {
  border: 1px solid color(neutral, light);
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;

  &__term {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: font-weight(bold);
    padding: 1rem;
    min-width: 16rem;
    border-right: 1px solid color(neutral, light);

    &:not(:first-child):after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 1rem;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      border-top: 1px solid color(neutral, light);
    }
  }

  &__item {
    float: left;
    padding: 1rem 0;

    &:after {
      content: ',';
      margin-right: .25rem;
    }

    .b-references__term + & {
      content: '';
    }

    dt + & {
      padding-left: 1rem;
    }
  }
}
```

There is a few problems with this approach though:

1. If a set's `<dd>`'s exceed the width given, they break to the next line and fall under the `<dt>` not the other `<dd>`'s.
2. I can't figure out a way to remove the comma from the last `<dd>` in each set. I can't target it by checking if it is followed by a `<dt>`.
3. If there are multiple `<dt>`'s for a set, I'm not sure how to define the styles so all of them are comma separated within the same "cell" like the mockup.

[image: working version]

I'm assuming many solutions will involved simply using a table, but semantically a dl makes much more sense, so I'd like to try to get this to work if I can. Any help is much appreciated!

```css
.b-references {
  border: 1px solid color(neutral, light);
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.b-references__term {
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: font-weight(bold);
  padding: 1rem;
  min-width: 16rem;
  border-right: 1px solid color(neutral, light);
}

.b-references__term:not(:first-child):after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 1rem;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid color(neutral, light);
}

.b-references__item {
  float: left;
  padding: 1rem 0;
}

.b-references__item:after {
  content: ',';
  margin-right: .25rem;
}

.b-references__term+.b-references__item {
  content: '';
}

dt+.b-references__item {
  padding-left: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<dl class="b-references">
  <dt class="b-references__term">Director</dt>
  <dd class="b-references__item">Edgar Wright</dd>
  <dt class="b-references__term">Cast</dt>
  <dd class="b-references__item">Ansel Elgort</dd>
  <dd class="b-references__item">Lily James</dd>
  <dd class="b-references__item">Jon Hamm</dd>
  <dd class="b-references__item">Jamie Foxx</dd>
  <dd class="b-references__item">Kevin Spacy</dd>
  <dd class="b-references__item">Elza Gonzalez</dd>
  <dd class="b-references__item">Jon Bernthal</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: Curious as to how you consider a definition list to be more semantic than tabular data, which you have. How is _Edgar Wright_ the definition of _Director_?

Comment: According to the HTML5 spec, a DL is not strictly a definition list. Paraphrased from the spec: "The dl element represents an association list consisting of zero or more name-value groups (a description list). A name-value group consists of one or more names (dt) followed by one or more values (dd)."

When a list can have more than one term (Writer and Director for Edgar Wright) or more than one description (the list of actors and actresses under Cast) then a DL is the most appropriate choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an answer if you're able to use CSS3 grids.

The only thing this requires are pairs of `<dt>` & `<dd>`, and nesting elements inside of the `<dd>` into another list.

With this approach, you're free to style the list of directors/cast independent of the `<dl>`.
Here, I used CSS to make it look like a bunch of comma separated names.

```css
.b-references {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.b-references__term,
.b-references__item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
  padding: 20px;
}

.b-references__term:last-of-type,
.b-references__item:last-of-type {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.b-references__term {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.b-references__item {
  border-left: 1px solid lightgray;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.comma-separated-list {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.comma-separated-list>li {
  display: inline;
}

.comma-separated-list>li::after {
  content: ", ";
}

.comma-separated-list>li:last-of-type::after {
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<dl class="b-references">
  <dt class="b-references__term">
    <ul class="comma-separated-list">
      <li>Director</li>
      <li>Writer</li>
    </ul>
  </dt>
  <dd class="b-references__item">
    <ul class="comma-separated-list">
      <li>Edgar Wright</li>
    </ul>
  </dd>
  <dt class="b-references__term">
    <ul class="comma-separated-list">
      <li>Cast</li>
    </ul>
  </dt>
  <dd class="b-references__item">
    <ul class="comma-separated-list">
      <li>Ansel Elgort</li>
      <li>Lily James</li>
      <li>Jon Hamm</li>
      <li>Jamie Foxx</li>
      <li>Kevin Spacy</li>
      <li>Elza Gonzalez</li>
      <li>Jon Bernthal</li>
    </ul>
  </dd>
</dl>
```

**Edit:** Wrapped dt contents into a list too, and added a special list class for comma-separated lists.

Comment: Yeah this could definitely work for cases with a single dt and multiple dd's, but what about in a case like the Writer/Director where we need multiple dt's for a single set?

Comment: @Alex The simplest option is to wrap them into a list too. But in the end, you have to decide where to draw the line between total semantic correctness and the ability to style it without immense effort.

Comment: `<dt>`s cannot contain block elements, though.

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dt) says `<dt>` may contain flow content except some certain elements (headers, footers, ...). Where did you get that information from?

Comment: Sorry, I was looking at the html spec and misread, you are correct.